# Which one suits better UI or DSL?

Tags: dsl

We have a system whose behavior is defined by a number of XML files.(Roughly 50 different XML files each of which governs the behavior of a sub system.)

The XML files for legacy reasons are in a custom format,meant for easy consumption by various components in the system.

The custom format is not very intuitive and readable for a human.(Which is also an important consideration for us).

So how do we tackle this readability issue?

I feel that an intuitive UI written on top of these XML files should do the job.

However my co worker feels that replacing XML files with DSL is a better idea, since they can be both intuitive and machine readable.

Is this a good idea or an overkill? I feel that getting DSL right is extremely hard compared to say a UI. But I could be wrong.

Any help would be greatly appreciated. Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

An XML-to-XML translation is a half-way solution and is probably the approach I'd use.

A UI has to be very complete before it's a replacement for a text-based description of behaviour, and common text-based idioms such as copy & paste, search & replace etc. are awkward to implement with good usability in a UI.

However, a full-blown DSL with a custom parser is probably a step too far, particularly if there isn't parser or compiler experience in multiple members of the team. Don't get me wrong - I don't think people should be afraid of parsers, I'm a compiler engineer myself - but it's a fact that some folks are fearful, and if the parser isn't done right, it can get messy quite quickly.

So, I'd advocate designing an idealized XML format, and write a tool that transforms that format into your real XML format either with XSLT (if it's easy - I wouldn't get too deep into XSLT functions etc.) or a simple translation app.

There are lots of advantages to having a readable text format for specification: ad-hoc editing is easy (you only need notepad), diffs from source control are readable, snippets can be emailed around, etc. Getting a UI that has usability and functional parity with a text format is not easy.

Comment: Thanks for the information Barry. By idealized XML format do you mean a much more readable form of XML that can be hand written or tweaked by a programmer directly? A couple of guys in our team have some experience using lex/yacc. However none of them have written full blown experience in compiler writing.

Comment: Also how do you ensure that the user editing the files gets it right and does not commit mistakes inadvertently? Wouldn't this mean a custom editor with a some auto completion feature and a means of validation after editing? (We want non conforming data to be flagged as soon as possible)

Comment: Prashanth - how do you guarantee that people don't check in source code that doesn't compile? The answer is usually some variant of continuous integration, automated builds that email the team when errors show up, and shames folks into not breaking the build. Semantic errors are usually a far worse problem than syntactic errors.

Comment: Yes what you say makes perfect sense.

Answer (score 2):

You should look at http://www.eclipse.org/Xtext/ - it's great for what you are looking for!